# How to create a desktop short cut Ubuntu use a custom command

Tags: ubuntu, shortcut, desktop

i want to create a desktop shortcut that execute a command Line example:

`/home/Xerty/document/wine executable.exe`

How I can do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Not hard. Create a file on your desktop (most likely `~/Desktop`) that looks like this. I'll pretend the script is named `shortcut-demo` and it is in `~/Desktop`.

```bash
/usr/bin/env bash
/home/Xerty/document/wine executable.exe
```

Open a terminal and run `chmod +x ~/Desktop/shortcut-demo`. This makes it executable (so you can run it), the `/usr/bin/env bash` means it is a Bash script (TBH simple `sh` would work fine, but I like Bash). The line after that is the command you want to run. You can have multiple commands there.

Note: specify the full path to `executable.exe` (i.e., `/home/cocomac/Downloads/something/executable.exe` instead of `executable.exe`)